# PHP: Cannot redeclare class error after return

Tags: php, include, return

I'm trying to protect classes being redeclared by returning based on if class_exists. This is common when creating plugins in Wordpress as there may be multiple plugins using the same classes. Using the following trivial example:

You can view this on Youtube at http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=llVTvh6ffmw

The following link demonstrates the problem and the root cause http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcNLoDvRLDc

**index.php**

```
<?php
include_once('debug1.php');
include_once('debug2.php');

$test = new SomeClass();
echo $test->someVar;
```

**debug1.php** & **debug2.php** are duplicate files...

```
<?php
if(class_exists('SomeClass')) return;
class SomeClass {
    var $someVar = "test";
}
```

Despite having a return statement we still get a fatal error "cannot redeclare class".

On a side note: Oddly 80% of the time this code has worked by simply adding/removing whitespace in debug2 - by work I mean it runs once then it breaks.

I am running PHP version 5.4.4.

So my question is. Is this expected behaviour? If yes, what am I missing. If no, is worrying as I've seen this in a few Wordpress plugins.

Please note: I can get it to work every time with else wrapping, but this is more code...:

```
<?php
if(class_exists('SomeClass')) return;
else {
    class SomeClass {
        var $someVar = "test";
    }
}
```

Comment: This problem is best solved with autoloading, so it doesn't make any sense to suggest alternative approaches unless you give specific constraints up front (and explain why they cannot be lifted).

Comment: Thanks Jon - your right autoloading would bypass this problem but am more interested in whether this is expected behaviour especially as other well known plugins use it e.g. [Wordpres Github Plugin Updater](https://github.com/jkudish/WordPress-GitHub-Plugin-Updater/blob/master/updater.php)

Comment: It is expected behavior, yes. And again, it doesn't make sense to do things like that unless you are operating under particular constraints.

Comment: Just to clarify - this code is being used in plugins by other developers that are being downloaded daily. As a result I would like to know more about this - or at least provide a good place for people to spot there is a potential mistake they should avoid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can confirm that this is a difference with how xcache is compiling/installing the code. 
By default PHP install's classes during compilation and then removes the class code so that it won't be installed again on execution. This is known as early binding. During this process the install of the second class would fail as the "class exists" and the code will remain intact for execution.

Upon execution PHP will have a second go at installing any remaining classes in the same order as the code this is known as late binding. Any classes which are not reached during execution such as in debug2 are not installed and so do not cause an error. This provides a level of flexibility which allows bad practice such as instantiating a class before it is declared. Or in this case avoiding duplicate includes by checking if the class exists rather than being more diligent with your includes or make your life easier by using an autoload.

Whilst PHP allows this practice xcache have confirmed that they only execute early binding which in turn forces the class redeclaration error. (see: http://xcache.lighttpd.net/ticket/314)

As xcache is used a lot in live environments I would recommend against using a return statement without the else. However, as Jon said autoloading is the way to go, or else wrap the class within an else statement.

This video shows the inconsistency between xcache and PHP: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VcNLoDvRLDc

P.S. Jon's answer is right with the respect to how PHP parses the page, however I have created this more detailed answer as xcache was also having an effect on the results.

Comment: You should accept this answer as it is the result and a good explanation of what the problem you were running in to is. ^^

Answer (score 0):

Class structures can be defined anywhere within a document, and then used elsewhere.  It's the reason why you can declare classes at the end of the page, and utilize them at the beginning.  It's not a suggested practice, but does work.  It's due to how PHP parses the page.  If you wrap the class declaration in an `if/else` statement, then it is not executed until the condition is met (or the previous not met) - thus you negate the error of trying to re-declare an existing class.

Comment: Just to clarify your answer. In my example code anything under the if statement will not be reached in general if the if condition is met - irrelevant of whether it is wrapped in an else. However, PHP is parsing the complete file before this and so triggering a class redeclaration error even though the class will not be met. Why do you think PHP executes this successfully sometimes when playing with whitespace?

Comment: Depends on what you are doing with the whitespace.  It could be that it isn't being parsed properly at that point (and you say it crashes when doing that).  But without seeing how you got it to work with _just_ modifying the whitespace, I can't be sure to give you a decent answer.

Comment: Hi Jon - I have uploaded a small video which should demonstrate clearly what I am experiencing. I am not convinced yet by your answer due to the sporadic nature of how PHP is handling this.

Comment: Based on your video, I see you are using chrome which has some odd caching type features I've noticed before, which causes the error to appear on the second refresh.  Have you tried that with a different browser and get the same results?  (Safari/Firefox)?

Comment: Have just added an additional video which shows PHP handling return statement differently between included file and invoking file. You will see this is safari and I can reproduce the same error (same for firefox).